# Display array in XUL

Tags: javascript, arrays, xul

I have a javascript array of strings and I want to display below this in an XUL panel one below the other. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to create `<description>` elements for all the strings using the usual DOM methods:

```js
var strings = ["foo", "bar"];
var container = document.getElementById("panel");
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
{
  var description = document.createElement("description");
  description.textContent = strings[i];
  container.appendChild(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it many ways in XUL for example XUL tree, list, grids etc...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/listbox
http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/xul/listbox.xul
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tree#A_tree_with_several_columns
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Grids

Please refer the links for example code.